# count objects from an array with that object and count of that object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers

I have this code snippet. and want to count duplicate applicationType along with applicationType and count both.

```
   {
    applicationType:"Supplemental Marketing Application",
    createdBy:"System"
},
{
    applicationType:"Supplemental Marketing Application",
    createdBy:"System"
},
{
    applicationType:"Orphan Application",
    createdBy:"System"
},
{
    applicationType:"Orpahn Application",
    createdBy:"System"
},
{
    applicationType:"IND/BB",
    createdBy:"System"
}
```

I want to count application type along with application type name also, and want result like this,

```
{
    applicationType:"Supplemental Marketing Application",
    count:"2"
},
{
    applicationType:"Orphan Application",
    count:"2"
},
{
    applicationType:"IND/BB",
    count:"1"
}
```

or

```
applicationType = [Supplemental Marketing Application,Orphan Application,IND/BB]
count = [2,2,1]
```

Comment: First decide yourself how you want? And then, don't forget to try yourself. If you get stuck after that, post a question.

Comment: I can use any one from suggested result. I tried many ways but not able to get same result like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to create a map, grouped by aapplication type. Check if the application type is present in the map or not, if it already exist in the map than update the count by 1 else map it with the default count of 1. `Object.values()` on the map will give you the desired output:

```js
let arr = [ { applicationType:"Supplemental Marketing Application", createdBy:"System" }, { applicationType:"Supplemental Marketing Application", createdBy:"System" }, { applicationType:"Orphan Application", createdBy:"System" }, { applicationType:"Orphan Application", createdBy:"System" }, { applicationType:"IND/BB", createdBy:"System" } ];

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, curr)=>{
  a[curr.applicationType] = a[curr.applicationType] || {applicationType : curr.applicationType, count : 0} ;
  a[curr.applicationType].count++;
  return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reduce function and check if in the accumulator array if there exist an key whose value matched with value of `applicationType` from original array
If `findIndex ===-1` then create a new object with these values from original array and then push in the accumulator , else if it already exist then update the value of count

```js
let orgArray = [{
    applicationType: "Supplemental Marketing Application",
    createdBy: "System"
  },
  {
    applicationType: "Supplemental Marketing Application",
    createdBy: "System"
  },
  {
    applicationType: "Orphan Application",
    createdBy: "System"
  },
  {
    applicationType: "Orpahn Application",
    createdBy: "System"
  },
  {
    applicationType: "IND/BB",
    createdBy: "System"
  }
]
let newArray = orgArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.applicationType === curr.applicationType
  });

  if (findIndex === -1) {
    let newObj = {}
    newObj.applicationType = curr.applicationType;
    newObj.count = 1
    acc.push(newObj)
  } else {
    acc[findIndex].count += 1

  }


  return acc;


}, []);

console.log(newArray)
```